# Xcode build done. Failed to build iOS app - Flutter project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am getting the below error after upgrading flutter to the latest stable version.
Executed all the possible commands to clear the catch and install the pods.

```
Xcode build done.                                           12.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[3394]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f5995eb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1063384f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[3394]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f5995f00) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106338548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[3394]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f5995f50) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106338598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[3394]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f5995fa0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1063385e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[3394]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f5995ff0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106338638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[3394]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f5996040) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106338688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    2022-03-20 16:20:58.949 xcodebuild[3394:27451] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-03-20 16:20:58.949 xcodebuild[3394:27451] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/p3/k59gspbd78s4bpfvpwpz4ct80000gn/T/flutter_tools.a1tf9R/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir0CdVEj/temporary_xcresult_bundle
In file included from /Users/aravindganesh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
/Users/aravindganesh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
In file included from /Users/aravindganesh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTWKProgressionDelegate.m:5:
/Users/aravindganesh/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter_wkwebview-2.7.1/ios/Classes/FLTWKProgressionDelegate.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @ErickFilho, Yes, actually, I cleaned the flutter cache, restarted mac and reopened my IDE and IOS simulator. Seems to be some cache issue. Try clearing the catch and restart mac.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere the same symbol / class is defined twice.

- Check the frameworks linked to see if there are any duplicates. If so remove the duplicate
- Clean build folder (Command + Shift + K)
- If simulator, then reset the simulator and try
- If device, restart the device and try